# How does one add a custom field/attribute to the customer addresses?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, customer-address

[This link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html) explains it for the addresses in the checkout.

But in want to add a attribute to the normal customer addresses that are displayed in "My Account"

I have an entry in my di.xml, but this alone doesn't work:

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
    <attribute code="company_2" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```